# Nested symbolic x coords in bar chart

Tags: pgfplots

any ideas on how to create something like this in latex? [image]

the image is of a basic grouped plot (using pgfplots) but with a nested x axis group (the numbers in red) that I've added using an image editor. how could I go about adding multiple nested groups in latex?

or if it's not possible, could I instead just manually add the second group as a label underneath the chart?

Comment: There many examples similar to this in the [`pgfplots` manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots).  What have you tried?